# shell_exec() and exec() on a local WAMP server not working

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I am trying to execute a python script through php on my wamp server but it does not allow me. It does not throw an error, and simply returns nothing. Running php in terminal works, so its in the apache/php settings in wamp.

I've read that you need to disable **safe_mode_exec** in php.ini in apache settings, however the feature is deprecated and not present in php 6.0 or over. How do I enable **exec()** and **shell_exec()** in new versions of php, mine being **7.4.26**?
I also searched for the **disable_functions** string in php.ini, and it is empty by default, and adding something there, like just *'exec'* does not help.

Comment: Need more information than "does not allow me".  What error(s) do you get.

Comment: I am pretty sure that php raises an error if it somehow blocks such a call. Where did you look for error messages?

Comment: I use a try-catch and print the errors so the client will recieve the message either way - client recieves nothing

Comment: Use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout so you can actually see the error messages produced.

Comment: I would suggest to check for the disable_functions setting.  make sure exec and shell_exec are not present here. If they are, remove them from the list.

and the safe_mode setting. If it is enabled (safe_mode = On), you need to disable it (safe_mode = Off). good luck!